# Top Navigation Showing All

Tags: 2010, navigation, breadcrumb

I was asked by a co-worker this morning if it were possible to have the Top Navigation bread crumbs show all sites within the path.  As of right now it only shows 3 jumps from the site you currently reside, I am trying to see if there is an Out of the Box (ootb) way to set this up.  Below is an example of what we see now - The Parent Site - Next Level - ... (accounting for 3 not shown sites) - Archives (current site)

[image]

I was poking around in the Site Navigation but could not find what I needed.  I am working in SharePoint 2010 and have SharePoint Designer 2010 if that helps.

Any Assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this tag

```
<ASP:SITEMAPPATH runat="server" hideinteriorrootnodes="true" rootnodestyle-cssclass="breadcrumbRootNode" currentnodestyle-cssclass="breadcrumbCurrentNode" nodestyle-cssclass="breadcrumbNode" rendercurrentnodeaslink="true" sitemapproviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider">
```

Full reference : http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/04/10/improve-the-sharepoint-breadcrumb-navigation-aspx/

Comment: Thank you for this!  I'm going to give it a try right away.